# One-dimensional motion, instantaneous velocity and speed, equation question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A particle's velocity is given:
>
> $V_y (t) = -at $
>
> $a = .758 m/s^2 $ is a constant
>
> Describe the particle's motion, in particular, is it speeding up, slowing down, or maintaining constant speed.

So my resulting graph is going to be a velocity vs time graph, right? I think so because a = (m/s^2) and t = s, so doing the multiplication you get (m/s) so I'm fairly sure on this.

Now, is it true that if I was to take the slope at any time on this graph, it would give me my average velocity?

And, in this case, speed is the magnitude of displacement, divided by time, right?

Taking values of t(300) = -227.4, t(0) = 0, t(1) = -.758, I keep on getting the same slope.

Doesn't this mean that the velocity is constant? My book says that it is speeding up, but I was thinking that its maintaining constant speed because the slope isn't changing.

Can anyone explain to me why it's speeding up?

Comment: The equation is $V_y (t) = -at $,
At t=0 ,
$V_y (t) = 0$
At t=1 ,
$V_y (t) = -a$
At t=2 , 
$V_y (t) = -2a$

Comment: Velocity is not the slope of all graphs that you plot, it is the slope of $x-t$  graph (in this case $y-t$ graph).

Comment: Okay, so graphing the function given by the equation you do get a velocity vs time graph, right? I thought for a velocity vs time graph, for it to be accelerating or decelerating, the slope has to change at some point? The slope on this graph doesn't change..

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the velocity $V_t(t)$ against the time $t$ will be a straight line passing through the origin and of gradient $-0.758$.

The gradient of the graph is the acceleration which you found to be constant and the particle is speeding up in the negative direction.

The area under the graph between two times is the displacement of the particle between those two times.

Comment: Okay, so I understand that it's "suppose" to be speeding up because of the acceleration, but when I plot this graph I find that is has a slope that is constant throughout the whole equation. Since it is a velocity vs time graph, does that not imply that that it is actually not accelerating? I'm confused.